# Omit author in biblatex verbose style (starred cites)

Tags: biblatex

With biblatex styles such as `authoryear`, I can use the starred version of cites commands to omit the author name (for instance `\parencite*{key}`). How can I do the same with `verbose`?

More specifically, I only need this in cases where I discuss and cite an author inside a footnote. The following MWE outputs :

> 1. Bourdieu argues that blah blah (Bourdieu, *La distinction*, Paris: Minuit, 1979).

What I want is :

> 1. Bourdieu argues that blah blah (*La distinction*, Paris: Minuit, 1979).

This is what I get if I replace `verbose` with `authoryear`:

> 1. Bourdieu argues that blah blah (1979).

(Obviously, with `authoryear`, I would have written "Bourdieu (1979) argues" instead)

```
\begin{filecontents}{Test.bib}
@book{bourdieu1979,
author = {Bourdieu, Pierre},
title = {La distinction},
location = {Paris},
publisher = {Minuit},
year = {1979}
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Test.bib}     

\begin{document}
Here is a footnote\footnote{Bourdieu argues that blah blah \parencite*{bourdieu1979}.}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at [Suppress author option: remove the name of an author already used in text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262401/35864)

Comment: @moewe Thank you, that is just what I was looking for.